# Install OpenCV 3.2 with VS2010 in Windows 8 for 64 bit

Tags: opencv

I want to use OpenCv3.2 in Visual studio 2010,I am using windows 8, 64 bit and install OpenCV 3.2 and done the environment variable setting as append Path:`OPENCV_DIR%\bin;C:\Program Files\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin and also add Libraries in VS2010 from Project Properties->VC ++ Directories->C:\Program Files %28x86%29\opencv\build\include`

And add all the hpp files in .cpp file in project.
The included files are:

[image]

```
# include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"

# include <iostream>

# include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

# include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"

# include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

All are included only # include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp" is not getting included due to which I can't use the  SurfFeatureDetector methods because included in the opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp.

```
/**
   * @file SURF_detector
   * @brief SURF keypoint detection + keypoint drawing with OpenCV functions
   * @author A. Huaman
    */

       #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
       #include <iostream>
       #ifndef HAVE_OPENCV_NONFREE

       int main(int, char**)
       {
        std::cout << "The sample requires nonfree module that is not        available in your OpenCV distribution." << std::endl;
        return -1;
       }

       #else

       # include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
       # include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
       # include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
       # include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"

       using namespace cv;

       void readme();

       /**
        * @function main
        * @brief Main function
        */
       int main( int argc, char** argv )
       {
         if( argc != 3 )
         { readme(); return -1; }

         Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
         Mat img_2 = imread( argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

         if( !img_1.data || !img_2.data )
         { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

         //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
         int minHessian = 400;

         SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

         std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

         detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
         detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

         //-- Draw keypoints
         Mat img_keypoints_1; Mat img_keypoints_2;
                                                                                      drawKeypoints(img_1,keypoints_1,img_keypoints_1,Scalar::all(-1),            
         DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );
    drawKeypoints(img_2,keypoints_2,img_keypoints_2,Scalar::all(-1),             
          DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT );

         //-- Show detected (drawn) keypoints
         imshow("Keypoints 1", img_keypoints_1 );
         imshow("Keypoints 2", img_keypoints_2 );

         waitKey(0);

         return 0;
         }

/**
 * @function readme
 */
void readme()
{ std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_detector <img1> <img2>" << std::endl; }

#endif
```

Comment: _"C:\Program Files\opencv\build\x64\vc14\bin"_ you're using OpenCV prebuild for Visual Studio 2015 (vc14). You need to rebuild OpenCV for Visual Studio 2010 (vc10)

Comment: Can we install OpenCV 3.2 with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Yes, but you need to recompile OpenCV